# ArrayList Limit to hold 10 Values

Tags: java, android

I am using an `ArrayList` within my code which gets populated by a `EditText` field but I am wanting to limit the `ArrayList` so it can only hold 10 values. After 10 values have been added if another tries to get added I just need it to not add into the `Array`. Anyone got any ideas how to do that?

```
private static ArrayList<String> playerList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: Have you tried using an array instead of a list? 
`String[] myarray = new String[10];`

Comment: ArrayList is faster & mutable than String[]

Comment: ArrayList is certainly not faster than an array, especially since ArrayList uses an internal array to store data. The reason to use lists rather than arrays is that lists are more flexible, part of which functionality op wants to remove.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your handler method:

```
if(playerList.size() < 10) {
   // playerList.add
} else {
   // do nothing
}
```

**Edit**: Your mistake is here:

```
if(playerList.size() < 10) {

    Button confirm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
    confirm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    EditText playername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userinput);
    playerList.add(playername.getText().toString());
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    playername.setText("");

    }});
} else {
       // do nothing
}
```

You should check the size inside the `onClickListener`, not outside:

```
    Button confirm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
    confirm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText playername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userinput);
            if(playerList.size() < 10) {
               playerList.add(playername.getText().toString());
               adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
               playername.setText("");
            } else {
                // do nothing
            }
        }
     });
```

Comment: I am trying to implement this but it still adds more than 10, can you take a look at this http://pastebin.com/LZAxHzdQ just check I have implemented it correct?

Comment: I really prefer the solution offered by @sapan-diwakar...it is more elegant and object oriented: you delegate to the list to handle it's size.

Answer (score 10):

If you don't have control over the function that adds elements to the list, you might want to override the `ArrayList` `add`.

```
public class MySizeLimitedArrayList extends ArrayList<Object> {
  @Override
  public boolean add(Object e) {
      if (this.size() < 10) {
          return super.add(e);
      }
      return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: You should return false on the else or after the if, otherwise it will not compile.

Comment: Its obvious but we need to override addAll methods as well. Interesting part is should we add part of given collection or not in case of size overflow.

Comment: This is good but you should say that it doesn't work for addAll

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayList` doesn't have a way of limiting the size; you could extend it to include a limit:

```
public class FixedSizeLimitedArrayList extends ArrayList<Object> {
  @Override
  public boolean add(Object o) {

      int n=10;
      if (this.size() < n) {
          return super.add(o);
      }
      return false;
  }
}
```

Other options include:

- Use an array, which is limited.
- Modify the code that uses the list to enforce the limit (e.g. [ArrayList Limit to hold 10 Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969805/arraylist-limit-to-hold-10-values))
- Find a list implementation that has a limit (some examples listed here): [Any way to set max size of a collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196113/any-way-to-set-max-size-of-a-collection)

Answer (score 0):

You modify you setter method like this.

```
private static ArrayList<String> playerList = new ArrayList<String>();

public boolean addToPlayerList(String input) {
   if (playerList.size() < 10) {
      playerList.add(input);
      return true;   
   } else {
      return false;
   }
}
```

Or

You can extend `ArrayList` and create your own customized class.

```
public class MyArrayList extends ArrayList {
  @Override
  public boolean add(String input) {
      if (this.size() < 10) {
          return super.add(input);
      } else {
          return false;
      }
  }
}
```