# How do you limit the size of an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I am trying to create an empty ADT Bag that can hold up to 100 items.

```
public class ListArrayListBased implements ListInterface {

   private ArrayList<Object> data;

   public ListArrayListBased() {
        this.data = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

How do I make an ArrayList limited to 100 objects?

Comment: new ArrayList<Object>(100);

Comment: @towhid this only sets the initial capacity, it is not a limit

Comment: You can create an array (`new Object[100]`) and then use `Arrays.asList` to make a `List` that can't be modified

Comment: You can't limit the size of the list. But you can pre-fill a list and create an unmodifiable collection after you've filled your list by invoking [`Collections.unmodifiableList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List))

Comment: ArrayList is not meant to have a limit. You should rather wrap the ArrayList in a class (`ADTBag` for example) and implement yourself that logic

Comment: It's a possibly a duplicate of

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969805/arraylist-limit-to-hold-10-values/8969931

Comment: What is an “ADT Bag”, and why did you mention that?

Answer (score 3):

You can't limit the size of an `ArrayList` directly, but since it's not exposed and can only be added to through the `ListArrayListBased`'s methods, you can check the size explicitly. e.g.:

```java
public void add(Object o) {
    if (data.size() >= 100) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("data is full");
    }
    data.add(o);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could override the add method. There may be other methods that also need to be overriden.  I believe though that `addAll` calls `add`.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>() {
    @Override
    public boolean add(Integer v) {
        if(size() < 10) {
            return super.add(v);
        }
        return false;
    }
};

for (int i = 0; i< 11; i++) {
    System.out.println(list.add(i));
}
```

Prints

```
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
false
```

Comment: Just checked the source code (should have done it sooner).  Apparently, the current implementation of `ArrayList.addAll` does not call `add`.

Comment: There are four add methods, `add(Integer)`, `add(int,Integer)`, `addAll(Collection<? extends Integer>)`, and `addAll(int index, Collection<? extends Integer>)` and there’s no guaranty that either calls the other. Further, there’s `list.listIterator().add(…)` which currently does delegate to `list.add(index, element)`, but this might change. There’s also the possibility that future versions of `ArrayList` offer additional ways to add elements. That’s why you should extend classes designed for extension, i.e. `AbstractList<E>` guarantees that all add operations use `add(int index, E element)`.

Answer (score 1):

## `List.of( array )`

You can pass an array to [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E...)) resulting in a [non-modifiable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable) `List` with a fixed size of the array’s size. Elements cannot be added, removed, or replaced.

```
Object[] arr = new Object[100] ;
… populate array 
List< Object > objs = List.of( arr ) ;
```

---

## Circular buffer (a.k.a. cyclic buffer, or ring buffer)

Or, perhaps you want a non-blocking queue which automatically evicts elements from the head of the queue when attempting to add new elements onto the queue and it is full.

If so, see [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21699069/642706) on the Question, [*Is there a fixed sized queue which removes excessive elements?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1963806/642706). There I mention `EvictingQueue` from Google Guava, and `CircularFifoQueue` from Apache Commons.

To instantiate an `EvictingQueue` call the static factory method [`create`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/EvictingQueue.html#create-int-) and specify your maximum size.

```
EvictingQueue< Person > people = com.google.common.collect.EvictingQueue.create( 100 ) ;  // Set maximum size to 100.
```