# Best way to maintain a list in java

Tags: java

I have a list of objects which get created by a factory class and for the time being I want to limit the list size to 10 objects. I also need to maintain the list through out the program as multiple classes will be referencing its values. I don't want to create it as a singleton and im not happy about having a master class maintain it, so is there another way? (Best Practice)

Comment: If the values in your lists are constant, you could use Enums

Comment: The list contains location data and other data describing any area. Hence the values may change. Since the list is limited to a size of 10, as a new area is created, an old areas data in the list is replaced with the new ones data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For setting the max size you can refer to this post here [Any way to set max size of a collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196113/any-way-to-set-max-size-of-a-collection)

Not sure what you mean by "maintaining" the list though. There is no way (that I know of) to make that list accessible to all classes without having it in a "master class".  The only other option is passing it through functions.

Comment: That's what I thought but a master class is bad design and handing around the list breaks encapsulation. As a side note, what would happen if the program tried to assign a value past the max limit of the list? Ignore that, I read further into the link  you provided.

Comment: If your application will only ever have a single list of locations, then there's nothing wrong with making a singleton manager class that can add/delete from this list. This way the manager can also limit the size of the list if necessary and remove any elements that are too old.